# Дублируются значения при использовании нескольких JOIN (извлечение данных при нескольких связях многие ко многим) PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Уже 3 вопрос по одному SQL запросу, но постоянно возникают новые проблемы =).

**Входные данные**: PostgreSQL. Есть 5 таблиц: `products`, `colors`, `sizes`, `products_to_colors`, `products_to_sizes`. Связь многие ко многим - каждый продукт может иметь несколько цветов и несколько размеров. Каждый цвет и размер может быть у нескольких продуктов. Связь между цветами, размерами и продуктами реализована с помощью 2 таблиц `products_to_colors`, `products_to_sizes`.

**Поля в таблицах**:

1. products - `id`, `name` (остальные не имеют значение, упрощаем задачу =) )
2. colors - `id`, `color` (в `color` указывается сам цвет, например, зелёный)
3. colors - `id`, `size` (в `size` указывается сам размер, например, `XL`)
4. products_to_colors - `id`, `color_id`, `product_id`
5. products_to_colors - `id`, `size_id`, `product_id`

Мне нужно достать данные из этих таблиц и получить модели товаров. Пробовал использовать такой запрос:

```
SELECT 
    products.*,
    string_agg(colors.color, ',') AS colors,
    string_agg(sizes.size, ',') AS sizes
FROM products
    LEFT JOIN products_to_colors ON products.id = products_to_colors.product_id
    LEFT JOIN colors ON colors.id = products_to_colors.color_id
    LEFT JOIN products_to_sizes ON products.id = products_to_sizes.product_id
    LEFT JOIN sizes ON sizes.id = products_to_sizes.size_id
GROUP BY products.id
```

В ответе от postgres значения sizes и colors продублированы, т.е.:

```
"id": 4,
"name": "test",
"colors": "белый,желтый,белый,желтый",
"sizes": "38,38,48,48"
```

Почему это происходит и как я могу это исправить?

**P.S.** Ещё есть таблицы `images` с картинками (связь многие к одному - 1 товар, несколько картинок.), и `products_to_products` (в ней сохраняются похожие продукты). Их тоже буду использовать в запросе, пробовал их тоже в запросе использовать, тогда значения выводятся по 4 раза, а не по 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы умножаете между собой записи из `products_to_colors` и `products_to_sizes`, отсда и повторы. Делайте оба подзапросами примерно так:

```
(select string_agg(colors.color, ',')
 from products_to_colors
 JOIN colors ON colors.id = products_to_colors.color_id
 where products.id = products_to_colors.product_id) as colors
```

Comment: Не понимаю, куда я должен вставить этот подзапрос? В `SELECTED`? Попробую сегодня

Comment: Убрать соответсвующий LEFT JOIN и заменить этим подзапоросом агрегацию `string_agg(colors.color, ',') AS colors`